For graphs - is there tensor category such that invertible objects correspond to Jacobian/sandpile group of a graph?
Categorical definition of the Picard group - is just group of invertible objects in tensor category. For example line bundles on manifolds - since they are 1 dimensional can be inverted.
There is definition of Jacobian/Picard ("Sandpile", "Critical group") of the graph which has been attracted quite an attention recent years (see e.g. links here). It is defined as cokernel of the Laplacian and it should be thought as a kind of tropical limit of Jacobian of curves when curves degenerate to graphs.
Question 1: Can one attach some category (over Z) to graph such that its Picard group would be related to that Jacobian/Picard/Sanpile group ?
(May be get just p-torsion in that way ? If general case is difficult ).
Question 2: If we look on a graph as quiver (with  e.g. bidirected edges) and will consider category "quiver representations" but over Z (e.g. Z-modules). Will that category have something to do with the question above ?
